# multiple definition and namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, pragma, include-guards

Is that the right way to have functions in namespace that i will #include in multiple files?

test.h

```
#pragma once
    #ifndef TEST
    #define TEST
    namespace test{
    namespace {

        bool test(){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
#endif //TEST
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The include guard name `TEST` is likely to conflict with some other macro, use something more elaborate, like `HEADERNAME_H`.

Note: names that start with underscore followed by uppercase, and names that contain two successive underscores, are reserved for the implementation.

<del>Secondly, if you're going to put that in a header file, then the function definition needs to be `inline`. Otherwise, when included in multiple translation units you'll get a multiple definition linker error. Or more formally, the standard's ODR (One Definition Rule) forbids such multiple definitions, unless they're all `inline` and effectively identical.</del>

**Edit**: delete above because I didn't see your use of an *anonymous namespace*.

Instead of the anonymous namespace, which gives you a separate namespace in each translation unit and a separate (identical) function definition in each such namespace, instead of that just use `inline` – as explained in striked-out text above.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous namespaces make all identifiers they wrap ***unique to the translation unit*** they are in. Putting an anonymous namespace into a header that will (sooner or later) be included in different translation units will result in all the identifiers defined in that anonymous namespace to be separately (but identically) ***in each translation unit***.

I have yet to see a use case where one wants this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because it give you an ability to name the same things with same names and keep this names simple